# Libgit2Sharp Compile Time Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, libgit2sharp

I am working on a library that uses libgit2sharp and I am trying to include in an asp.net WEB API project.

The library itself builds without any issue. Also, Console and WPF projects that use the library I develop compiles without any issue. However, when I include the library in ASP.NET Web API project it gives the following error.

```
Failed to make the following project runnable: MYAPI(.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2) reason: The process cannot access the file 'c:\path\to\project\packages\libgit2sharp.nativebinaries.1.0.164\libgit2\libgit2sharp.dll.config' 
because it is being used by another process. MYAPI    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets    262
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the your file is in use by some *.vhost process you earlier started by debugging one of your applications. Visual Studio sometimes does not kill every process correctly.

Try the following

1. Close visual studio and start again
2. If 1. does not help, log of your windows account. Sign in again.

Comment: This wasn't the usual in use error and these did not fix I was just writing how I resolved the issue in this specific case.

I basically downloaded libgit2sharp source and built it myself rather than using nuget package. Then I copied Release folder to my project. After that I have included libgit2sharp.dll as a reference and then platform specific (win32/x64) git2-1196807.dll as a regular file with the copy to output directory setting set to always.